# Maven clean install unable to get artifact from maven central

Tags: maven

After cloning the remote repo on to Linux remote machine, I am getting the following errors when trying to run `mvn clean install`:

```
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1] [ERROR]
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable parent POM: Could not transfer artifact xxxxx
from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2):                                           Connection to http://repo.maven.apache.org refused and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 4, column 10: Connection timed out -> [Help 2]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] 
[ERROR] [Help 2]
```

These errors occur **only** when running `mvn` commands on Linux, the project builds successfully after `mvn clean install` on Windows environment...

Any ideas as to why this is happening on Linux machine?

Thanks

Comment: The error message indicated `Connection to http://repo.maven.apache.org refused and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 4, column 10: Connection timed out -> [Help 2]` some kind of network/firewall problem.

Answer (score 2):

> Connection to http://repo.maven.apache.org refused

The above message seems be due to network failure. As you say it builds successfully on windows and not on Linux, I envisage there must be some different network setting in your linux profile. Had you ever added any proxy? Check [maven proxy setting](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-proxies.html) and try again.

Comment: It could also mean the Windows host has the same connectivity issue (company firewall) but has cached/downloaded/installed the artifact in question before.